# Forward DM attachments in Discord with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want my discord bot to take a file sent to its Direct Messages into a specific channel in my server. I can get a normal text message forwarded. Here is my code currently

```
@bot.event 
async def on_message(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(*Channel ID Redacted*) # are you sure this channel exists?
    if message.channel == message.author.dm_channel: # do not use guild == None, as group dms might satisfy this, and you can't message yourself, no need to check client user
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = 'Sent to SFU Bots DMs!', #Title
            description = f'{message.content}', #1 line Content
            color = 0x9fffff #embed color
            )
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Sent by {message.author.display_name} | ID-{message.author.id}')
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
        print("Sent by {} | ID-{}!" .format(message.author, message.author.id))
        print("Content: '{}'." .format(message.content))
        print('Sent DM to Channel')
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

I have used the following code path to send files but not forward ones from DM channels:

```
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx):
    file = discord.File("myfilepath")
    await ctx.send(file=file, content="Message to be sent")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = await bot.get_channel(...)
    if not isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):  # don't do anything if not in dm
        return
    else:
        if message.attachments:  # check if there are any attachments
            for img in message.attachments:  # iterate through list of Attachment objects
                await channel.send(img.url)  # send attachment url to your channel
        else:
            print("No attachments.")  # do nothing if no attachments are received
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```